# Uniform covergence of a series of functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\sum f_n $ be a uniformly convergent series of functions on the interval [a,b]. Does it imply that the series $\sum \sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f_n(x)|$ is convergent? Is it true if we also assume that the functions $f_n$ are continuous on $[a,b]$?

Comment: By $\sum f_n$ do you mean a sequence of functions $f_n$ or a sequence of functions $f_0, f_0+f_1, f_0+f_1+f_2, \ldots$.  The latter would usually be called a series rather than a sequence.

Comment: Thanks. I mean the series.

Comment: You don't even need to think about functions here - say each $f_n$ is constant.  it's not true that $\sum_n a_n$ converging implies $\sum_n |a_n|$ converges.

Comment: Pay attention to what @JairTaylor said here.

Comment: If that is the case what is the role of sup is there?

Comment: @FayuTola I don't know.  I wonder if you are missing some assumption on $f_n$, like positivity.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the sum you refer to converges is the normal convergence of the function series : $\sum \|f_n\|_{\infty}$ converges. Normal convergence implies uniform convergence but the reciprocal statement is generally false.
For example, consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x\mapsto\frac{1}{x+1}$ and the sequence of functions $\left(f_n\right)$ defined by $$ f_n(x) =  
\begin{cases}
f(x) & \text{if   } x\in [n,n+1] \\ 
 0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
 $$
then $\|f_n\|_{\infty} = \frac{1}{n+1}$ therefore $\sum \|f_n\|_{\infty}$ does not converge (harmonical series) but the series of function $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly

Comment: Not clear with reciprocal statement.

Comment: I just added a counter-example ;)

Comment: This is clear. Thank you.